# Templates - check if T inherits from A<Q>, where Q is a base class of T

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm struggling with a compile time check whether some class inherits from a template class:

```
template<typename T> class A { ... }

template<typename T> class B {
  T* ptr;
  bool test() {
    // shall return true, if T inherits from A<Q>, where Q is a base class of T (or T itself)
  }
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
  template<typename Q = T> typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A<Q>, Q>, bool> test(){
    return true;
  }
  template<typename Q = T> typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<A<Q>, Q>, bool> test(){
    return false;
  }
```

But this obviously won't work since it only checks whether `T` inherits from `A<T>`.

Comment: sounds tricky, if `T` inherits from `X` and `Y` you want to return true if `T` also inherits from `A<T>`, `A<X>`, or `A<Y>` without even a hint as to which one it could be?

Comment: Just to illustrate the question, you're looking for types like `struct T : A<T> {};` and `struct T : X, A<X> {};`, right?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: Yes, if this is possible somehow

Comment: @KerrekSB: In my exact scenario there's `struct M : A<M> {};` and `struct N : M {};`

Comment: @csk: To be clear, your test should say true for `M` and false for `N`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Let's define also `struct O {};` and `struct P : A<M> {};`. Then the test should return `true` both for `M` and `N`, but `false` for `O` and `P`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, makes sense. (I believe this cannot be done in standard C++, because you cannot enumerate base classes. The abandoned TR2 contained a `bases` trait, which GCC implements, but it's not portable.)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type=typename Tag::type;

template<class Q>
tag_t<Q> from_a_q(A<Q>*);

template<class X>
using a_q_r = type<decltype( from_a_q( (X*)0 ) )>;
```

now `a_q_r<X>` is the unique type `Q` such that `A<Q>` is reachable in the inheritance heirachy of `X`.

```
template<class X>
using a_q_test_prime = std::is_base_of_t< a_q_r<X>, X >;
```

this fails in a sfinae friendly manner if we have no `A<Q>` (or more than one).

We want better than that.

Write [`detected_or`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

```
template<class X>
using a_q_test=detected_or_t<std::false_type, a_q_test_prime, X >;
```

and if there is a single `A<Q>` accessible in the heirarchy of `X` and there is also an unambiguous base `Q` this is true, and otherwise false.

Apologies for any tpyos, on phone.